# What is wrong with this method for displaying images?

Tags: java, swing, methods, graphics, jlabel

I am very confused. Why would this method not work for displaying an image:

```
private void showImage(final BufferedImage image){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
        new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run(){
                ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
                JLabel label = new JLabel();
                label.setIcon(icon);
                add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

My class extends `JFrame`, so that's why I'm not doing something like:

```
frame.add(label);
```

I am very confused. I have tried this without the whole `SwingUtilities` thing and also I have tried `label.setVisible(true)`
What the heck am I doing wrong here? When I run it I know this method is being called with a completely okay `BufferedImage` (I had it output something in the method). I expected a `JLabel` to come up with my image on it, but just the JFrame came up, no image in sight.

Comment: That's quite unclear. Post a complete, minimal example reproducing the problem. Tell us what you expect it to do, and what it does instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

When you add (or remove) a component from a visible GUI the basic code is:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

In your case you would revidate the frame since you are adding the label to the content pane of the frame.

That is you need to invoke the layout manager, otherwise the component has a size of (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint.

However, a better solution would probably be to add the label to the GUI when you create the frame.

Then to change the icon you just do:

```
label.setIcon(...);
```

No need to create a new JLabel every time you want to change the image.

Comment: Are revalidate() and repaint() necessary?  I've never seen a case where they were needed with standard JComponents.

Comment: I just used `JDialogPane.showMessageDialog` and it actually did exactly what I wanted, but still thanks for the help.

Comment: Your fix sounds like a workaround. I'd go with the 'better solution' described above. Using that, we could even set an initial transparent image of WxH as a hint about minimum size. This is useful when packing the top level container (the `JFrame`).

Comment: @VGR "Standard" components like `JTextField`/`JButton` etc, post these kind of events internally. However, when you change the layout of a container (by adding or removing components), you're required to do this as the containers are lazy when it comes to been updated, which is a good thing, as you don't want to be wasting time when adding/removing multiple components at runtime